# If $\mathfrak{p}\ge5$, then $2^\mathfrak{p}\not\le\mathfrak{p}^2$?

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation, cardinals

I don't understand some passages of the following demonstration which is present in "The  Axiom of Choice" by Thomas Jech.

[image]

I don't understand

- why $|\mathscr{P}(C_n)|=2^n>n^2$ if we originally assumed $2^\mathfrak{p}\le\mathfrak{p}^2$,
- why $U=\{x_\xi\in C_\alpha:x_\xi\not\in g(\xi)\}\not=\varnothing$ and $f(U)\not\in C_\alpha\times C_\alpha$,
- why the constructed sequence $\{x_0,...,x_4,...,x_{(n-1)},...\}$ of length $\aleph$ is contrary to the definition of $\aleph$.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - why $|\mathscr{P}(C_n)|=2^n>n^2$ if we originally assumed $2^\mathfrak{p}\le\mathfrak{p}^2$,

The assumption that $2^\mathfrak{p}\le\mathfrak{p}^2$ is irrelevant.  Here $n$ is some finite ordinal greater than $4$, and so you can show by elementary methods (say, induction on $n$ and some simple algebra) that $2^n>n^2$.

> - why $U=\{x_\xi\in C_\alpha:x_\xi\not\in g(\xi)\}\not=\varnothing$ and $f(U)\not\in C_\alpha\times C_\alpha$,

The proof never claims that $U$ is nonempty and nothing goes wrong if $U$ is empty.  The idea here is just that you are implementing Cantor's diagonal argument: by Cantor's theorem, there does not exist any surjection $\alpha\to\mathscr{P}(\alpha)$, and thus there is also no surjection $C_\alpha\times C_\alpha\to \mathscr{P}(C_\alpha)$ since $C_\alpha$ is in bijection with $\alpha$ and $\alpha\times\alpha$ is in bijection with $\alpha$.  If $f$ mapped every element of $\mathscr{P}(C_\alpha)$ to an element of $C_\alpha\times C_\alpha$ then we could invert $f$ to get a surjection $C_\alpha\times C_\alpha\to \mathscr{P}(C_\alpha)$ and thus a contradiction by Cantor's theorem.  The definition of the set $U$ is just the explicit "diagonal element" of $\mathscr{P}(C_\alpha)$ that is a counterexample to surjectivity which is produced by the proof of Cantor's theorem.

To go through the details, let me first correct a couple errors in Jech's definition of $g$.  The definition should be $g(\xi)=f^{-1}(x_\eta,x_\zeta)$ where $(\eta,\zeta)=f_\alpha(\color{red}\xi)$ (here I correct a typo of Jech), or $\emptyset$ if $(x_\eta,x_\zeta)$ is not in the image of $f$ (here Jech forgets that $f$ may not be surjective).   Note that by this definition $g$ may not be injective as Jech claims but that is irrelevant to the argument.

Now suppose $f(U)\in C_\alpha\times C_\alpha$.  Then $f(U)=(x_\eta,x_\zeta)$ for some $\eta,\zeta<\alpha$ and there exists $\xi<\alpha$ such that $(\eta,\zeta)=f_\alpha(\xi)$.  By definition, then, $g(\xi)=U$.  But now by definition of $U$, $x_\xi\in U$ iff $x_\xi\not\in g(\xi)=U$, which is a contradiction.

> - why the constructed sequence $\{x_0,...,x_4,...,x_{(n-1)},...\}$ of length $\aleph$ is contrary to the definition of $\aleph$.

This is literally the definition of $\aleph$.  By definition, $\aleph$ is the least ordinal such that there is no injection $\aleph\to X$.

Comment: Okay, however  If $U$ were empty, how can I define a bijective function between $\aleph$ and $X$? Anyway it seems to me that $U$ is non empty because $g$ can't be bijective: infact if $\alpha< \aleph=\aleph(\mathfrak{p})$ then by definition of Hartogs number $-\aleph(\mathfrak{p})-$ and by Cantor's Theorem it must be $|\alpha|<\mathfrak{p}<2^\mathfrak{p}=|\mathscr{P}(X)|$. So what can you say to me about?

Comment: You're right that $g$ can't be bijective but that has absolutely nothing to do with whether $U$ is empty.  For instance if $g(\xi)=\{x_\xi\}$ for all $\xi<\alpha$ then $g$ is not bijective but $U$ would be empty.

Comment: And if $U$ were empty, how can I define a bijective function between ℵ and X?

Comment: No one ever said anything about defining a bijection between $\aleph$ and $X$.  The function $\alpha\mapsto x_\alpha$ which is constructed recursively in the proof is an _injection_ from $\aleph$ to $X$.  I have no idea what you think emptiness of $U$ has to do with anything.

Comment: Okay, I understand: rightly to contradict the definition of $\aleph$ it is sufficient to find an injection between $\aleph$ and $X$, right?

Comment: That is correct.